# Does QVariant expect a null-terminated QByteArray?

Tags: qt

I need to construct a QVariant object from a QByteArray. Does the QVariant constructor QVariant(const QByteArray & val) expect the raw bytes in the QByteArray to be null-terminated?

Background info:

My QByteArray object was constructed with QByteArray::fromRawData(const char * data, int size) and is not null-terminated.

My objective is to copy the raw bytes in my QByteArray object into a database with QSqlQuery::bindValue() which expects a Qvariant object as one of its arguments.

My guess is the the bytes in QByteArray must be null-terminated. I don't see any other way how QVariant(const QByteArray & val) constructor could be implemented.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bytes added in QByteArray may or may not be 0-terminated. If you convert QByteArray to QVariant, it will contain all bytes that have been added to the array regardless of their values. It's possible because QByteArray stores bytes count. When you have `char*` pointer and byte count, you can safely operate with bytes without knowing if there are 0s there or not.

Actually, when you call `data()` to get `char*` pointer, the data is always null-terminated. But it really is behind the scenes. If you use `data()` and pass that pointer to some function without size, 0-termination will protect you from segfault. But it is not important in your question.

I'll try to illustrate that using example.

```
Raw data: 1 2 3 4 ....
calling fromRawData(pointer, 4)
QByteArray contents: 1 2 3 4
Underlying QByteArray's buffer contents: 1 2 3 4 0 ...

Raw data: 1 2 3 0 ....   
calling fromRawData(pointer, 4)
QByteArray contents: 1 2 3 0
Underlying QByteArray's buffer contents: 1 2 3 0 ...

Raw data: 1 0 2 3
calling fromRawData(pointer, 4)
QByteArray contents: 1 0 2 3
Underlying QByteArray's buffer contents: 1 0 2 3 0 ...
```

And QVariant will contain the same bytes as "QByteArray contents".

Comment: Actually, the problem is with loading the QByteArray into a QVariant. As it does it through a const variable it does not make a deep copy and you cant be sure there will be a '\0'. ie. You can chain constData() calls and get a not null terminated array at the end. Check the gist i posted..

Comment: Deep copy can be done even from a const variable (e.g. `QString::QString(const QString &other)` does deep copy as pointed out in the docs). I suspect that deep copy internal variables are mutable. But this also doesn't matter. `QVariant` copies entire `QByteArray` value. It doesn't care about its underlying buffer. it doesn't call `constData` when constructing. Also, you must not chain `toByteArray().constData()` calls because the buffer returned by `constData` is valid only until the source object is destroyed, and the object is temporary and is destroyed immediately.

Comment: In your example on line 8, can you please confirm that you didn't make a mistake? I think the QByteArray contents will be 1 2 3 0 0 right? Must be I think. My data will actually be encrypted, so I don't necessarily know that some combination of bits somewhere in the middle might be representative of null. So I think in your last example, it's clear that there can be a null in the middle, but it really is part of the contents of the buffer. I think we can put this question to rest. Thank you to everyone!

Comment: I think that the fact that 'QByteArray *ensures* that the data is followed by a '\0' terminator' may mean that '\0' is not added when the data is already '\0'-terminated. But this note is quite pedantic. This fact shouldn't affect any well-written code.

Answer (score 0):

Edited for newcomers. Look at comments.

[From docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qbytearray.html):

> QByteArray can be used to store both raw bytes (including '\0's) and
> traditional 8-bit '\0'-terminated strings. Using QByteArray is much
> more convenient than using const char *. **Behind the scenes, it always
> ensures that the data is followed by a '\0' terminator**

It means, even if you dont make it null terminated, QByteArray will ensure it. But only when it creates a deep copy... Check [size()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qbytearray.html#size)

> int QByteArray::size() const
>
> Returns the number of bytes in this byte
> array. The last byte in the byte array is at position size() - 1. In
> addition, QByteArray ensures that the byte at position size() is
> always '\0', so that you can use the return value of data() and
> constData() as arguments to functions that expect '\0'-terminated
> strings. **If the QByteArray object was created from a raw data that
> didn't include the trailing null-termination character then QByteArray
> doesn't add it automaticall unless the deep copy is created.**

As prolly QVariant will use the constData() method, you cant be sure it will be null terminated.  Look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/trompa/a531a3240a8b57cd2251)

Comment: Confusing! Is the warning given at the end of documentation for QByteArray::fromRawData() a contradiction to the statement you emphasized in bold? Also, the warning states "QByteArray does not take ownership of data", so does it really add \0 behind the scenes?

Comment: Seems to me that QByteArray only adds '\0' if it makes a copy or is constructed in some other way than QByteArray::fromRawData(). I think if you use the constructor QByteArray(const char * data, int size = -1), as per documentation, it will make a deep copy and will then add '\0' behind the scenes. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Look at data() example. How it always returns \0.  Check how you have you reserve one more space or copy would break

Comment: So you are suggesting that the QVariant constructor uses QByteArray::data() function? Could be, and in that case I don't need to add the '\0' myself to the end of the QByteArray. Would be nice if someone could confirm this.

Comment: Note the constructor QVariant(const QByteArray & val) takes a const argument? Means you can't use QByteArra::data() since this function is not const. It then must use QByteArra::constData() and the documentation for this function says: "The data is '\0'-terminated unless the QByteArray object was created from raw data." So we are back to where we started - does constructor QVariant(const QByteArray & val) expect the raw bytes in the QByteArray to be null-terminated?

Comment: You were right, check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/trompa/a531a3240a8b57cd2251). Output is 4, X, Null terminated,4, undefined